# My app with ANE crashes after iOS 14.1 upgrade

Tags: ios, flash, sdk, air, ane

My app crashes everytime I call my custom ANE after upgrading to iOS 14.1.

The previous iOS versions are working fine.

I am using AIR SDK 32.0 and iPhoneOS13.1.sdk for compiling and packaging.

I removed my ANE and I tried packaging with 33.1.1.300 and I get this error:

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

"___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow", referenced from:

  __ZN26PlatformPrimitiveSocketTCP16HaveIncomingDataEv in libRuntimeHMAOT.arm-air.a(OSXPrimitiveSocket.o)

  __ZN14PlatformSelect12WaitForEventEjPb in libRuntimeHMAOT.arm-air.a(OSXPrimitiveSocket.o)

  __ZN20PlatformSecureSocket17WaitOnSocketErrorElNS_15WaitReadOrWriteEb in libRuntimeHMAOT.arm-air.a(CTSecureSocket.o)

  __ZN17MacDatagramSocket11ReceiveImplEPhPiR11FlashStringRiS3_S4_i in libRuntimeHMAOT.arm-air.a(OSXDatagramSocket.o)

  __ZN26PlatformPrimitiveSocketTCP16HaveIncomingDataEv in libRuntimeHMAOT.arm-air.a(OSXPrimitiveSocket.o)

  __ZN14PlatformSelect12WaitForEventEjPb in libRuntimeHMAOT.arm-air.a(OSXPrimitiveSocket.o)

  __ZN20PlatformSecureSocket17WaitOnSocketErrorElNS_15WaitReadOrWriteEb in libRuntimeHMAOT.arm-air.a(CTSecureSocket.o)

  __ZN17MacDatagramSocket11ReceiveImplEPhPiR11FlashStringRiS3_S4_i in libRuntimeHMAOT.arm-air.a(OSXDatagramSocket.o)
```

Then I tried to package using iPhoneOS14.0.sdk (dowloaded from https://resources.airnativeextensions.com/ios/), and I get this error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: I added the `Flash` tag since that sub-group might help you with the `AIR` issues.

Comment: If you have used the latest AIR SDK or linked against the latest iOS SDK then undefined symbols probably mean you are missing a framework dependency in your platform xml or are incorrectly packaging a library dependency?

Comment: Thank you. I shared the issue here: https://github.com/Gamua/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/512. I have been advised to remove the iOS SDK link. I could package but the problem persists (the App crashes everytime I call my ANE).